# CharlesProxy -Cisco Anyconnect - Android

Tags: android, ios, vpn, charles-proxy

Am unable to make CharlesProxy work on Android or iOS device.  The laptop and mobile devices are behind Anyconnect VPN.  Any pointers here would help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I had an issue with Charles and AnyConnect for a long time:

- If I opened Charles first, AnyConnect would just spin on the 'Contacting [host]...." and never open the panel to enter credentials.
- If I opened AnyConnect and connected to the host first Charles would not monitor any network traffic.

I stumbled on this (non-technical) solution which always works for me (though I don't understand why):

- Close both AnyConnect and Charles Proxy.
- Open AnyConnect and click the "Connect" button but do NOT enter your credentials yet.
- Open Charles.
- Enter you credentials to connect with AnyConnect.

VPN is now connected and Charles monitors all network traffic.

Works for me every time.

Comment: This answer changed my life. Works great with Proxyman.

Comment: I love you. For almost a year this is made my life hell

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I have to say this is Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on VVPN version. The main idea is to try different approaches

For example:

```
connect Charles Proxy -> connect VPN
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically, VPN doesn't cooperate well with any Proxy Tools.

You might fix it by open the Cisco AnyConnect VPN Preference -> Select "Block Connection to untrusted server".

Then opening Charles Proxy or Proxyman first, then open the VPN later.

[image: Cisco]

Comment: This didnt help.  Seems to be a technical limitation with Cisco.  The mobile VPN client doesnt allow us to use OEM settings